# Getting locations in neighbourhood, for a given latitude and longitude.

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude

Given a latitude and longitude, how do i get the localitites around, saying that i mean, say i am in can i get a dataset having names of major locations in neighbourhood, or some tourist spot near it?

say i am in paris and have the lat and long    { lat : 48.8565, lng : 2.3509 },      // paris
could get some json/xml with stuffs like {"Eiffel Tower", "Arsenal"} etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not up on non-USA sources of geo data, but the USGS (United States Geological Survey) publishes an official gazetter of place names including latitude and longitude of the primary point (for a city, typically city hall or similar) of that place.

http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm

I successfully used this data in the past by loading it into PostgreSQL and using it's [geospatial query](http://postgis.refractions.net/) capability.